# Реляционные модели (active record) в yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Возникла необходимость работать из одного контроллера с несколькими таблицами БД, а значит и с несколькими моделями.

На Yii работаю впервые и такую задачу решаю впервые. Вопрос вот в чём: Как связать 2 модели? Нашёл много постов про выполнение реляционного запроса для получения данных уже из связанных таблиц. А вот как связать-то их? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Например, в классе News делаешь связь с категориями 1 к 1 (это значит, что 1 новость имеет только 1 категорию, может находиться только в 1 категории)

```
public function getCategory() {     
     return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']); 
}
```

Далее в коде, когда находишь конкретную новость, можешь обращаться через "связь" к категории новости

```
$news = News::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
echo $news->name; // Название новости
echo $news->category->name; // название категории, в которой находится новость.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCategory() {     
     return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']); 
}
```